# Python / Sqlite database not updated after commit but no error is returned

Tags: python, sqlite

I had to write a python script that can be restarted at some specific points if something gone wrong during the execution . For this purpose I have a little database where I store the current state and a complex object serialized.
The problem is that the request that update the state seems to be OK but the 'total_change' returned is 0 . And after read back , it confirms the data was not written in the database. Here's the code:

def check_error(l_data, code):
    global state
    if code > 0:
        process_error(l_data, state, code)

```
else:
    if state < 8:
        pdata = pickle.dumps(l_data, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        # pointing to the next state to resume
        state += 1
        try:
            logger.info('Updating state database')
            conn = sqlite3.connect(state_database)
            conn.execute('''UPDATE state_table SET state=?, object=? WHERE name=?''', (state, sqlite3.Binary(pdata), l_data['name']))
            conn.commit()
            logger.info('Number of rows updated: %s', str(conn.total_changes))
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            logger.error('Error writing state database: %s' % str(e))
            logging.shutdown()
            sys.exit(52)
        except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
            logger.error('Error writing state database: %s' % str(e))
            logging.shutdown()
            sys.exit(52)
        finally:
            conn.close()

        logger.info('-- New state : %s --', str(state))
```

I'm using the field 'name' of my saved object to make the request. 
I'm really stuck with this and I really don't see what's wrong :-/
Thanks in advance !

Yann

Comment: Your UPDATE can succeed without error but still not update the DB.  Are you sure `l_data['name']` exists within `state_table`.  You may want to use `conn.execute('SELECT * FROM state_table WHERE name = ?', (l_data['name'],))` to confirm the record you are trying to update actually exists.

Comment: @pathfinderelite : the commit() is done :)